# Why would I not be able to read the params on the REPL of my error page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to debug a particular issue and I have the gem `better_errors` installed. I get a nice looking error page that has an embedded REPL that allows me to check the values of various elements of the current request.

This is the URL that generated the error:

`http://localhost:3000/nodes/new?parent_id=16`

The issue is, when I try to check the value of the params I get this error:

```
>> params[:parent_id]
!! #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Node:0x007fc4db2cd678>>
>> node_params
!! #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `node_params' for #<Node:0x007fc4db2cd678>>
>> node_params[:parent_id]
!! #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `node_params' for #<Node:0x007fc4db2cd678>>
>> params
!! #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Node:0x007fc4db2cd678>>
>>
```

This is despite the Request Info section right below telling me this:

Request info

```
Request parameters  
{"parent_id"=>"16", "action"=>"new", "controller"=>"nodes"}
```

The REPL does work, as can be seen by this:

```
>> Node
=> Node(id: integer, family_tree_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, name: string, ancestry: string, ancestry_depth: integer, max_tree_depth: integer)
>> Node.first
=> #<Node id: 7, family_tree_id: 2, created_at: "2015-01-17 18:22:13", updated_at: "2015-01-17 18:24:50", name: "Self", ancestry: nil, ancestry_depth: 0, max_tree_depth: 0>
>>
```

Not sure if it matters, but this is the error message on the original request:

```
NoMethodError at /nodes/new
undefined method `parent_id' for #<Node:0x007fc4db2cd678>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That implies that you are inside of a method that as `self` as a `Node` object, not inside of the controller method. Look at the stack trace on the left side to see what method (and what object) you are currently executing code under.

Comment: `Node#method_missing` it seems. But I don't understand....isn't `params` simply an ActionController method?

Comment: Yes, but you aren't inside of an ActionController object, you are inside of a Node object. When you type something in the repl in better_errors, you are sending that method to the current object. In this case, it's a Node object. It's just like a debugger where you can step in and out of frames and what you can look at changes.

Comment: You are right. I just did `self` and it returned the `Node` object.

Comment: So how do I step back and actually get to my params, given that they are in the information under `Request Parameters`?

Comment: In the left hand side bar, there is a list of frames. You are currently in `Node#method_missing`, scroll until you see a frame that is in your controller, and click on it, then you will be in the proper context